# Boostrap collapsing scrollbar hide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, overflow

https://www.bootply.com/1qzmF59lc1

When you click the navbar right button,

the scroll bar is shown and disappears.

When I add this

overflow-y: visible;

I see afterimages.

I do not want to see the scrollbars, and the afterimages, too.
How do I fix it?
[image]

Comment: I didn't see the scrollbars over there. Can you show the screen shot ?

Comment: Yes, screen shot uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css code to your stylesheet
Scrollbar will remove using this code

```
.navbar-collapse.collapsing{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Well come @canfas